# Allow two developers to work on the same file at one time

Tags: filesystems, github, collaboration, dropbox

Apart from the obvious choice of GitHub, $7 a month, i was looking for a free simple way for two developers to work on the same file and to make independent changes without overwriting the others changes. I went for dropbox but this creates a second "copy" file, which is just not ideal.

Has anyone had any free, tried and tested way to do this.

We're both on Macs if that helps?

Comment: Try putting the git repository on Dropbox

Comment: @Mark, so you're suggesting not using GitHub but just using Git with DropBox?

Answer (score 1):

[BeanstalkApp](http://beanstalkapp.com/) has a free plan, and you can use either SVN or Git. If it's open source, you can use [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/).

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention, but Beanstalk's free plan does limit you to one user, but you could always share the user creds, if that's acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that, might give this one a go! :)

Comment: @benhowdle89 I use Beanstalk for hosting what was my capstone project. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have a SVN set up using VisualSVN on an old crappy XP box I have, it is fully functional simple to set up and works well with tortiseSVN, but if you don't want to host it yourself, there are plenty of free repositories hosts online which will most likely be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using git on dropbox. You will need to make sure you don't both update at the same time but still workable if you both have local repositories and push to the git clone that you put in Dropbox.

Another alternative is if one of the machines used is permenantly connected then have a git clone on that and run a git server accessible to the other machines. If your ISP gives a dynamic IP adress use a dynamic dns provider like dyn-dns.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is open source, you have a variety of options to get free SVN services: [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) being probably the most popular ones. SVN doesn't really allow branching quite as nicely and cleanly as Git, though, which seems to be what you're looking for.

One often overlooked service that I have used in the past [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/)'s free hosting. It is one of the few that also allows private repositories for non-open-source projects, and also has Git hosting as well as SVN (although I haven't used their Git hosting before).

The plan that I really recommend you take a look at is their [free Git hosting plan](http://offers.assembla.com/free-git-hosting/), which seems to be exactly what you need. It allows for unlimited repositories and users, although you are limited to 1GB of storage.